# Wordpress display how many articles published in custom posts type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have simple issue but seems like not displaying correctly my query. I would like to set the number of posts in my custom posts "Simple Download Monitor" so that I can set the conditions to my article class. Here's my simple code.

#### Code Fig. 1

```
<?php $io_articles = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'sdm_downloads', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'desc'] ); ?>
<div class="section-io-list-articles">
<?php 
if ( $io_articles->have_posts() ) : 
  $count = wp_count_posts()->publish;
  if ( $count >= 3 ) {
    $class_column = 'column-3';
  } 
  elseif ( $count == 2 ) {
    $class_column = 'column-2';
  }
  ?>
  <div class="section-content <?php echo $class_column; ?>">
    <div class="row">
    <?php 
      while ( $io_articles->have_posts() ) : $io_articles->the_post();
      ?>
      <article class="column"> <?php the_title(); ?> </article>
      <?php 
      endwhile;
    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php 
  endif; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</div>
```

`$count` usually display 1 instead of more than 1 post(s) if I echo it. By this, I have specific class set from that `$count` to support my article columns where you can see the conditions.

**Note:** I have 4 post(s) here, so it should display 4 as the number of `$count` which it should set the column class as `class="section-content column-3"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just missing what the wp_count_posts( $type ) usage. So the code should look like this.

```
$count = wp_count_posts( 'sdm_downloads' )->publish;
if ( $count >= 3 ) {
  $class_column = 'column-3';
} 
elseif ( $count == 2 ) {
  $class_column = 'column-2';
}
```